# Why and how do electrons move so much?

Tags: electrons

Why do Electrons move so fast and why. I already tried the physics classroom but I can't seem to find the right answer .

Comment: Are you imagining them as little balls or something? They are probability waves spread out over the whole space, they don't "move" at all, rather change or evolve. But at the level of little balls photons "move" even faster.

Comment: Hi.Could you tell us where did you read that 1)they move 2)they move fast?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons move quickly because they have low inertia. Their mass is so low that a small push gets them to a high speed.